# Rust: lifetime checking of a borrow inside a refernce to a MaybeOwned

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm having trouble with the follwoing code...

```
use std::collections::BTreeSet;
use maybe_owned::MaybeOwned;

struct Thing<'a, T> {
    set: BTreeSet<MaybeOwned<'a, T>>
}

impl<'a, T: Ord> Thing<'a, T> {
    fn take(&mut self, x: T){
        let y = self.set.take(&MaybeOwned::Borrowed(&x));
    }
}
```

gives the compiler error

```
error[E0597]: `x` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:10:53
   |
8  | impl<'a, T: Ord> Thing<'a, T> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
9  |     fn take(&mut self, x: T){
10 |         let y = self.set.take(&MaybeOwned::Borrowed(&x));
   |                 ------------------------------------^^--
   |                 |                                   |
   |                 |                                   borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                 argument requires that `x` is borrowed for `'a`
11 |     }
   |     - `x` dropped here while still borrowed
```

However x is clearly not borrowed at that point because the MaybeOwned has fallen out of scope and therefore the enclosed borrow has fallen out of scope.

How can I tell the rust compiler that this is fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, while the temporary `MaybeOwned` doesn't live that long, it doesn't matter because it's implicitly `MaybeOwned<'a, T>`.  This means `x` must live at least as long as `'a` but it doesn't.  The fact that the temporary `MaybeOwned` won't live that long isn't relevant to the borrow checker.

`BTreeSet::take()`'s second argument is a `&Q`, where the set's own `T` implements `Borrow<Q>`.  `MaybeOwned<'a, T>` doesn't implement `Borrow<MaybeOwned<'b, T>>` where `'b: 'a`, but all `T` and `&T` implement `Borrow<T>` thanks to a blanket implementation, so given an argument typed `&MaybeOwned<'_, T>`, the only lifetime that satisfies the `T: Borrow<Q>` constraint is `&MaybeOwned<'a, T>` -- thus, the lifetime parameter of the temporary `MaybeOwned` is inferred to be `'a`.  That's the only way the trait bounds can be satisfied.

Thankfully, none of this matters, because `MaybeOwned<'_, T>` implements `Borrow<T>`, which means you can just supply a `&T`:

```
let y = self.set.take(&x);
```